# postscript on two pages blurs first page

Tags: postscript

I would be grateful for help.
I have the following two short postscript files:

Code A

```
%%Pages: 2
%%Page: 1 1
/Times-Bold findfont 200 scalefont setfont
54.0 180.0 translate
0.050400 0.050400 scale
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 setrgbcolor
  1675   1675 moveto
(  page one) show
showpage
%%EOF
```

This prints "page one" on the first and only page of the document.

Code B:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0

%%Pages: 2
%%Page: 1 1
/Times-Bold findfont 200 scalefont setfont
54.0 180.0 translate
0.050400 0.050400 scale
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 setrgbcolor
  1675   1675 moveto
(  page one) show
showpage
%%EOF
%%Page: 2 2
54.0 180.0 translate
0.050400 0.050400 scale
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 setrgbcolor
  1675   1675 moveto
(  page 2) show
showpage
%%EOF
```

This prints "page one" on the first page and "page 2" on the second page. But it blurs out
the printing on the first page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Which PostScript implementation are you using? The code itself doesn't do that so (it seems to me) the problem must lie elsewhere, outside the code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment-indeed, the culprit was my ps to pdf converter...thanks.